# How to create a write-behind cache from inmemory to database?

Tags: java, spring, caching

My goal is to cache data inmemory for 60s. As soon as the entry is read again from cache, I want to remove it from cache (permit single reads only).

If those 60s expired in the meantime and the entry is still available in cache, I want to writebehind the entry into a database.

Is there any existing technology/spring/apache framework that already offers such a cache?
(sidenote: I don't want to use complex libraries like redis, ehcache etc for such a simple usecase).

If set up manually, I'd be doing as follows. But probably there are better options?

```
@Service
public class WriteBehindCache {
    static class ObjectEntry {
        Object data;
        LocalDateTime timestamp;

        public ObjectEntry(Object data) {
              this.data = data;
              timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        }
    }

    Map<String, ObjectEntry> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    //batch every minute
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
    public void writeBehind() {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        List<ObjectEntry> outdated = cache.values()
             .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().timestamp.plusSeconds(60).isBefore(now))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

        databaseService.persist(outdated);
        cache.removeAll(outdated); //pseudocode
    }

    //always keep most recent entry
    public void add(String key, Object data) {
        cache.put(key, new ObjectEntry(data));
    }

    //fallback lookup to database if cache is empty
    public Object get(String key) {
        ObjectEntry entry = cache.remove(key);
        if (entry == null) {
            entry = databaseService.query(key);
            if (entry != null)  databaseService.remove(entry);
        }
        return entry;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has two problems:

- You are doing a sequential scan for persisting, which will get costly when there are a lot of entries
- The code has race conditions
- Due to the race conditions the code does not satisfy your requirements. Its possible to construct a concurrent access sequence where an entry is removed from the cache but as well was written to the database

> Is there any existing technology/spring/apache framework that already offers such a cache? (sidenote: I don't want to use complex libraries like redis, ehcache etc for such a simple usecase).

I think you can solve the concurrency issues based on the `ConcurrentHashMap`. But I don't know an elegant way for the timeout. Still, a possible solution is to use a caching library. I'd like to offer an example based on [cache2k](https://cache2k.org) which is not heavy (about a 400k jar) and has other nice use cases as well. As an extra there is also good support for the Spring caching abstraction.

```
public static class WriteBehindCache {

  Cache<String, Object> cache = Cache2kBuilder.of(String.class, Object.class)
    .addListener((CacheEntryExpiredListener<String, Object>) (cache, entry)
      -> persist(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();

  public void add(String key, Object data) {
    cache.put(key, data);
  }

  public Object get(String key) {
    return cache.invoke(key, e -> {
      if (e.exists()) {
        Object v = e.getValue();
        e.remove();
        return v;
      }
      return loadAndRemove(e.getKey());
    });
  }


  // stubs
  protected void persist(String key, Object value) {
  }

  protected Object loadAndRemove(String key) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

With this wiring the cache blocks out concurrent operation on one entry, so it is certain that only one database operation runs for one entry at a time.

You can do it in similar ways with other caching libraries. Using the JCache/JSR107 API the code would look almost identical.

A more "lighter" approach is to use jhalterman's [expiringmap](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap)

Personally, I believe a cache should be in every developers toolbox. However, I am the author of cache2k. Of course, I need to say that.